# playframework, enter works, but clicking button does not work....what's wrong?

Tags: playframework

I have this very simple html page I ported from seam to playframework....the enter key works and I see a log printed telling me the email, but clicking the input button does not work.  any ideas what is wrong with my html? I thought I had this matching the play framework examples :(

```
#{extends 'template.html' /}
#{set title:'Registration for Premonition X' /}
#{set desc:'This is the registration page for Premonition X and all other applications in our marketplace'/}

<div class="regico lt"></div>
<div class="logindiv rt">
    <h2 class="title">Register</h2>
    <br/>

    #{form @registerStep2(), id:'register'}
    <div id="register:emailDecorate">
        <div class="entry">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
            #{field 'email'} 
            <span class="label ${field.errorClass}">Email:</span>
            <span class="input ${field.errorClass}">
                <input type="text" name="${field.name}" value="${flash.email}" class="boxtpl"/>
                <a id="newinfo" class="help" title="&{'help.email'}">Help</a>
                <span class="error">${field.error}</span>
            </span>
            #{/field}
        </div>
    </div>
    <br/>
    <br/>

    <div class="bt_box">
        <span class="btn_next">
            <input type="button" value="Next" class="btn"/>
        </span>
        <span class="btn_cancel">
            <a href="@{Web.home()}" class="btn">Cancel</a>
        </span>
    </div>

    #{/form}        
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dang, one of those typos you spend hours on.  type needs to be submit not button :( ...finally figured it out.